# Añadir Titulo de Json en java

Tags: java, json

Obteniendo en el response de webService algo así

```
[{"id":1, "name":"ejemplo1"}, {"id":2, "name":"Ejemplo2"}]
```

Esto es un ejemplo similar, pero esto debería ser;

```
{"Ejemplos":[{"id":1, "name":"ejemplo1"}, {"id":2, "name":"Ejemplo2"}]}
```

Estoy intentando hacer:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
j.put("ejemplos" , response);
```

pero el resultado es:

```
{"Ejemplos":"[{"id":1, "name":"ejemplo1"}, {"id":2, "name":"Ejemplo2"}]"}
```

pone ejemplos como string y me añade unas comillas en ->"<-[{"id":1 y las cierra en o2"}]->"<- como si el json fuera todo un string.

gracias.

Comment: Debe ser algo como `j.put("ejemplos" , response.get(0));`. Ahora mismo no sé decirte cómo exactamente hacer este `get(0)` porque no tengo delante nada.

Comment: Cuando quiero que salga un array devuelvo un "List" y tengo una clase llamada "x" que tiene de atributo "DATOS[] Ejemplos" y en la clase Datos tiene de atributos id y name. todo con sus get,set, constructor vacío y todos constructores. Así lo hago yo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por las respuestas.

Para convertir el json en un listado de objetos utilice la librería Gson.

```
Clase_Obj nombre = new Gson().fromJson(json, Classe_obj.class);
```

Con esto no hace falta darle un nombre ya que se genera el objeto.

Para array de objetos con la misma librería:

```
 final Type nombre_type = new TypeToken<List<Clase_obj>>(){}.getType();
 final List<Clase_obj> nombre_list = new Gson().fromJson(json, nombre_type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar de la siguiente manera añadiendo el array completo a un objeto JSON:

```java
ObjectMapper objmapp = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> arrmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

String resultJson = jsonArray.toString();

arrmap.put("Ejemplos", resultJson);

resultJson = objmapp.writeValueAsString(arrmap);
```